# How to Compare Two Column as Condition in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to compare two column as condition in Eloquent Laravel.
For example:
I have 3 columns, qty_1, qty_2, and price.
I wanto to get product which price under 1000 if column qty_1 and qty_2 are equal.
I have tried these codes but not working:

```php
Product::whereColumn('qty_1','=','qty_2', function($query){
    return $query->where('price','<', 1000);                        
});
```

How to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
Product::whereColumn('qty_1','qty_2')
  ->where('price','<',1000)
  ->get();
```